# Display is blank when plugged in docking station

Tags: release-juno, display

When notebook is booted when plugged in the docking station, all displays are used properly. When plugging out and in again without reboot in the docking station, only one screen is used, but shows a blank screen with only the mouse visible.
This worked fine up to a recent update (of course, I don't know which one)

How can I figure out which update caused the problem and where can I report this bug?

Hardware: HP Elitebook, HP Docking with 3 Displays (2xDP,1xVGA)
Software: elementary OS Juno with all patches